# Как отключить отображение кнопки назад (DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) в главном активити?

Tags: android, activity, android-fragment

Есть активити и фрагмент в фрагменте стоит `DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. При переходе с активити в фрагмент кнопка назад появляется все хорошо, но при нажатии и перехода назад в активити стрелочка остается отображаеться? Как убрать?

Пробывал не помогло:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
```

Код кнопки в фрагменте `DisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`:

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Код активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
    private static FragmentManager mManager;
    Button button1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

       /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

       // button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment = null;


                mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new sovety_Fragment();
                        mManager.beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                    }

            }


    });
    }



    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) { onBackPressed(); return true; }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Если `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` не помогает, значит Вы это где то не там вызываете. Точнее не в тот момент.

Comment: а в как в какой момент нужно?

Comment: После закрытия фрагмента полагаю, когда она и должна пропасть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете код, убирающий стрелку **до** того, как её показываете.

Т.к. вы убираете фрагмент нажатием кнопки "назад" именно в слушателе её нажатия надо убирать стрелку.

Засим попробуйте добавить обработчик нажатия кнопки назад в активити и именно в нём убрать стрелку:

```
@Override
onBackPressed()
{
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: `if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                onBackPressed();
            {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                super.onBackPressed();
            }  }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }` добавил код сюда но при нажатии на кнопку назад в фрагменте  выходит з приложения

Comment: помогите написать код, я незнаю как написать обработчик к стрелочке

Comment: `super.onBackPressed();` вызывайте только если Вам нужно выйти из приложения.

Comment: СПАСИБОООООООООО УРАААААААААААААА РАБОТАЕТ))))))

Answer (score 3):

Вы вызываете `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);` (прячете кнопку назад) при создании активити, затем добавляете на активити фрагмент, в котором показываете эту кнопку, но вы не прячете её снова при удалении фрагмента. Так с чего бы она должна пропасть.

Добавьте вот такой метод в активити:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1);
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Тоже думал добавить это в ответ, но в гугл было лень лезть) Вы пробовали код? У меня есть подозрение, что и без ручного удаления фрагментов из стека стандартное поведение кнопки назад должно будет отобразить предыдущий фрагмент.

Comment: Код писал по памяти, раньше точно так надо было, сейчас действительно в onBackPressed активити из сапорт либки добавили подобный код. Но тогда не понятно почему у автора вопроса при вызове super.onBackPressed() завершалась активити.